# Replace a whole block of code, part of an HTML for another block, with BS4 in Python

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I want to replace a whole code structure using bs4, I have a source html and a target html

```
t_soup = BeautifulSoup(target_html, 'html.parser')
s_soup = BeautifulSoup(source_html, 'html.parser')
```

The first code is in the target:

```
//Block of code number 0
<div class="td-module-thumb">
    //Some html code
</div>

//Block of code number 1
<div class="td-module-thumb">
    <a href="this_is_an_url.html" rel="bookmark" class="image-wrap">
       <img width="356" height="220" class="entry-thumb" src="../my_image-356x220.jpg" >
    </a>
</div>
```

and I want to replace what is contained in the target, specifically in block[1] for what is contained in the source in block[1], that is:

```
//Block of code number 0
<div class="td-module-thumb">
    //Some html code
</div>

//Block of code number 1
<div class="td-module-thumb">
    <a href="another_url.html" rel="bookmark_2" class="new-class">
       <img width="356" height="220" class="exit" src="../other_image_here.jpg" >
    </a>
</div>
```

They have the same `<div class="td-module-thumb">`

My code to make the replacements is the following:

```
left_column_selector = 'div.td-module-thumb'
left_column = s_soup.select(left_column_selector)[1]
```

NOTE:

```
>>> type(s_soup.select(left_column_selector)[1])
<class 'bs4.element.Tag'>
```

This are different tries of my last line of code, the one that actually makes the replacement:

```
// #1
t_soup.select(left_column_selector)[1].replace_with(str(left_column))

// #2
t_soup.select(left_column_selector)[1].string.replace_with(left_column)

// #3
t_soup.select(left_column_selector)[1].string.replace_with(left_column.string)

// #4
t_soup.select(left_column_selector)[1].replace_with(left_column.string)
```

Everything works fine except the las line of code. In consequence the code in target is not getting replaced for source

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it wholesale, as it were - delete target, insert source:

```
selector = 'div.td-module-thumb'
to_graft = s_soup.select(selector)[0]
for div in t_soup.select(selector): 
    div.decompose()
t_soup.select_one('doc').insert(1, to_graft)
```

Edit:

Let's say your files look like this:

```
target = """<root> I am the target
<div class="td-module-thumb">
    don't touch me!
</div>
<div class="td-module-thumb">
    replace me!
    <a href="this_is_an_url.html" rel="bookmark" class="image-wrap">
       <img width="356" height="220" class="entry-thumb" src="../my_image-356x220.jpg" >
    </a>
</div>
</root>
"""
source = """<root><div class="td-module-thumb">
    I'm the irrelevant part of the source
</div>
<div class="td-module-thumb">
    move me to target!
    <a href="another_url.html" rel="bookmark_2" class="new-class">
       <img width="356" height="220" class="exit" src="../other_image_here.jpg" >
    </a>
</div>
</root>
"""
```

Then this should do it:

```
t_soup = bs(target,'lxml')
s_soup = bs(source,'lxml')
selector = 'div.td-module-thumb'
to_graft = s_soup.select(selector)[1]
to_remove = t_soup.select(selector)
to_remove[1].decompose()
t_soup.select_one('root').insert(2, to_graft)
t_soup
```

Output:

```
<root> I am the target
<div class="td-module-thumb">
    don't touch me!
</div><div class="td-module-thumb">
    move me to target!
    <a class="new-class" href="another_url.html" rel="bookmark_2">
<img class="exit" height="220" src="../other_image_here.jpg" width="356"/>
</a>
</div>

</root>
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'insert'  
What could be happening?

Comment: @TheDan Don't know; works on my end. Try editing your question and showing a more complete (but short!) representative samples of both files, including root elements.

Comment: @TheDan See edit and let me know if it works this way.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it by performing Javascript. Import [Pyv8](https://code.google.com/archive/p/pyv8/) and change the parent's container **innerHTML** value. The script below returns true if the replacement worked.

```
import PyV8
ctx = PyV8.JSContext()
ctx.enter()

print ctx.eval(document.getELementById('#parentContainer').innerHTML = newhtml; if (document.getELementById('#parentContainer').innerHTML == newhtml) {return true;} else {return false;})
```

Comment: This is invalid syntax(even for py2), and the question asker is using Python 3 anyways.